# Why is the Forum Design lagging behind?

Tags: community, design, ubuntu-forums

Way back when Ubuntu 10.04 was released Canonical changed the branding of Ubuntu to the orange/purple combination which I kind of like so why more than one year later the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) still look like this:

[image: Ubuntu Forums Website Header]

So why the long wait?

Comment: I would have used Sexy in the question but joey trademarked it

Comment: Foolishly I left my User ID in the screenshot which means I will be getting hate mail from OMG fans :(

Comment: Here's a nice stylish/stylebot user style that brings it a lot closer: http://userstyles.org/styles/40915

Comment: if they can do a userstyle why cant they style the actual site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There appear to be several technical issues impeding the progress of the new Ubuntu Forums theme. From a [thread back in 2010](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1518451) an Ubuntu Forums staffer [confirmed](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9530634&postcount=12) there were several mock-ups made but goes on to outline there are "technical issues" with vBulletin that are hindering it's progress.

Comment: Agree - latest thread I've found was back in feb this year - same "vbulletin" issue - but the promise it will be in-place when the new forums hardware was in-place- well the hardware is there - but no new theme :( http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1686078&highlight=theme

Comment: Migration from vBulletin or Compromise the theme what's more likely?

Comment: @Allan Migrating from vBulletin is incredibly unlikely